# Textmate2 default search location

Tags: textmate2

How do I change the default search location in Find (command-shift-F) for TextMate2? Right now it defaults to my home directory (which is almost never what I want), and I'd like it to search only the current files (as if you click the drop-down menu and select "Open Files") or `projectDirectory`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this little arrow on the File Browser drawer to access the pictured menu, then select `Use "____" as Project Folder`. After that, Command+Shift+F should have this directory selected in the Find dialog.

[image: Use "Blah" as Project Folder]

Comment: Wow. This is one of the most unintuitive designs I have seen. 1) The directory (e.g., `grahamh` in your example) is displayed in the window; there is no reason to suspect that it's not the `Project Folder`. 2) `The Use "____" as Project Folder` item is already checked for me, but it works as you said after I click it. Then if I bring up the drop down menu again nothing in the UI indicates anything has changed (except that Find defaults to the project directory now). 3) The setting doesn't stick. Thanks for finding such an obscure work around!

Comment: What do you mean the setting doesn't stick? Seems pretty solid to me.

Comment: Does adding `projectDirectory = '$CWD'` to a `.tm_properties` file located at the root of your project, or in your home directory make this behavior more inline with your expectations? I've had it for a while.

Comment: I have `projectDirectory = '$CWD'` in my home directory already. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: Maybe try removing it from your home directory's version, and only include it at the base of your project?